# accessing attrs in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to create an overlay (or modal window) in AngularJS and i created so far the html/css layout and to put it simple it looks like this

```
<section class="calendar">
    <a open-overlay="overlay-new-calendar">Add New Calendar</a>
</section>



<section class="overlay overlay-new-calendar">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <form class="wrap">
        <header>
            Add a New My Calendar
        </header>

        <div class="main">
            <label>Name<input type="text" required ng-model="newCalendar.calendar_name" /></label>
            <label>Color<input type="text" required ng-model="newCalendar.calendar_color" /></label>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
            <a close-overlay="overlay-new-calendar">Cancel</a>
        </footer>
    </form>
</section>
```

So what is going on here is i have an anchor `<a open-overlay="overlay-new-calendar">Add New Calendar</a>` where i add a directive open-overlay which i want to make generic and as attr to that directive to give the exact overlay to open. Now i tryed this

```
fixEvents.directive('openOverlay', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.bind('click', function() {
            alert(attr.open-overlay);
            $('.overlay-new-calendar').show();
        });
    }
});
```

But i can't get the attr to return `overlay-new-calendar`. Also how can i do the show, hide without jquery if anyone know :D Thank you very much, Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

peterorum is correct.

To elaborate on his answer, you need to:

1. I assume you have scope.newCalendar defined somewhere. Define scope.isNewCalendarOverlayVisible = false in the same place.
2. Add ng-click="isNewCalendarOverlayVisible=true" as an attribute on your link or button that you want to open the overlay.
3. Add ng-show="isNewCalendarOverlayVisible" to your overlay.

This way your overlay is watching that scope property to know whether it should be visible or not.  When the button is clicked, that property changes to true, and the modal becomes visible.

Comment: And make sure to set `isNewCalendarOverlayVisible=false` when you're ready for the form to be hidden again.

Comment: thank you very much for this, this just took me to a new level :)

Answer (score 2):

Showing or hiding without jQuery is done using an attribute e.g. "ng-show=myValue". So your directive would change the value of an model, e.g. scope.myValue = true;

Accessing your attribute should be attr.openOverlay, as attribute names are normalized in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

`attr` normalises the attributes on your element. The attribute `open-overlay` is treated the same as the `data-open-overlay` etc and is accessible through `attr.openOverlay`.

There is a little more information here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes)

For showing and hiding you can use *peterorum*'s answer of `ng-show`.